# Pandas applying a function to list of columns raises TypeError

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to clean multiple columns in pandas. I've following function to clean it:

```
def convert_dash_comma_into_float(num):
    if " -   " in num:
        num = num.replace(" -   ", "0.0")
    elif "," in num:
    num = num.replace(',', '')
    try:
        return float(num)
    except ValueError:
        return np.nan
```

When I apply this function on to a single column, it works.

```
df["rpks"].apply(convert_dash_comma_into_float)
```

But when I try to apply into a series of columns by providing a list because I've a bunch of them to clean, it raises TypeError

```
df[["rpks", 'asks', 'pax']].apply(convert_dash_comma_into_float)
```

TypeError: ("cannot convert the series to ", 'occurred at index RPKs First')

Here is some sample data which currently is in object type as 'O':

```
rpks    asks    pax
9.74    194.72  1,752.48
19.47   82.74   700.85
 -      360.16  3,679.45
127.03  994.14  7,306.93
53.54   612.75  5,770.53
 -      7.02    666.43
34.52   197.28  784.19
 -      460.31  5,466.80
 -      108.63  1,128.90
 -      16.54   913.49
10.52   368.06  3,054.90
93.93   784.55  5,646.55
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**`applymap`** with **`lambda`**

```
df[['rpks', 'asks', 'pax']].applymap(lambda r: '0.0' if '-' in str(r) else str(r).replace(',', ''))

      rpks    asks      pax
0     9.74  194.72  1752.48
1    19.47   82.74   700.85
2      0.0  360.16  3679.45
3   127.03  994.14  7306.93
4    53.54  612.75  5770.53
5      0.0    7.02   666.43
6    34.52  197.28   784.19
7      0.0  460.31  5466.80
8      0.0  108.63  1128.90
9      0.0   16.54   913.49
10   10.52  368.06  3054.90
11   93.93  784.55  5646.55
```

Comment: Hi, it works. But really why is that? Why lambda function works in this case but not the one I defined? Thx for looking into this.

Comment: Your function seems alright, except some of the columns are floats, so using `in` on a float results in an error.  Also using `apply` vs `applymap`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`pd.DataFrame.applymap`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) with your function.

However, I suggest you refactor your logic to check for `float` first as, if your data is representative, many values are already in an acceptable format.

Here's an example.

```
def converter(num):
    try:
        return float(num)
    except ValueError:
        try:
            num = num.replace('-', '0.0').replace(',', '')
            return float(num)
        except ValueError:
            return np.nan

cols = ['rpks', 'asks', 'pax']
df[cols] = df[cols].applymap(converter)

print(df)

      rpks    asks      pax
0     9.74  194.72  1752.48
1    19.47   82.74   700.85
2     0.00  360.16  3679.45
3   127.03  994.14  7306.93
4    53.54  612.75  5770.53
5     0.00    7.02   666.43
6    34.52  197.28   784.19
7     0.00  460.31  5466.80
8     0.00  108.63  1128.90
9     0.00   16.54   913.49
10   10.52  368.06  3054.90
11   93.93  784.55  5646.55
```

Comment: Thats a great point. I figured out the solution is to use applymap as you pointed out. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need a function here to apply, it consumes way more time. Just use the built in `replace`, it's fast and it can take dictionary as a parameter too i.e

```
df = df.replace({'-':0.0,',':''},regex=True)

    rpks    asks      pax
0     9.74  194.72  1752.48
1    19.47   82.74   700.85
2        0  360.16  3679.45
3   127.03  994.14  7306.93
4    53.54  612.75  5770.53
5        0    7.02   666.43
6    34.52  197.28   784.19
7        0  460.31  5466.80
8        0  108.63  1128.90
9        0   16.54   913.49
10   10.52  368.06  3054.90
11   93.93  784.55  5646.55
```